# Can't resolve symbol while trying to extend class from different package

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have following structure:

src\test\java\TestBaseClass.java

src\test\java\cucumber\CucumberTestBaseClass.java

When I want to extend TestBaseClass

```
public class CucumberTestBaseClass extends TestBaseClass {
}
```

I receive an error "Can't resolve symbol: TestBaseClass"
I use IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.2.3 but I have past projects when such extension is compiling so I don't have idea what is wrong here.
I have no idea what is going on becuase I have

Comment: Does TestBaseClass compile?

Comment: `TestBaseClass` is, presumably, in the default package. You can't import things from the default package. Move it into an explicit package, and import it.

Comment: @AndyTurner that was the problem. Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move TestBaseClass to some package
2. If CucumberTestBaseClass and TestBaseClass are in different packages make sure to import TestBaseClass in your CucumberTestBaseClass